# Function to find directly part of a document in a file without many arguments

Tags: python, string

Is there any python string(like .findall ,.find etc) where directly can find what is wanted? For example if we want in an html file all the hyperlinks where is included the 'www' to give something like:

```
html.findall(www)
```

Of course the syntax is not  right but one simple string without many arguments could help

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a string you would want to search, and the pattern you would want to search for?

Comment: You can use a regular expression and `re.findall()`.

Comment: If you are dealing specifically with HTML, you can use `lxml` to parse the document and XPaths or CSS selectors to specify the parts you're interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example that uses `re` module to find all websites that start with `www.`:

```py
import re

string = """<a href="stackoverflow.com>Stack Overflow"</a>
<a href="github.com">Github</a>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="www.madeupwebsite.com">Made Up</a>
<a href="pypi.org">PyPi</a>
"""

print(re.findall("(?!\")www.*(?=\")", string)) # Find all non-overlapping matches
```